# How to set a navigation title with a tab view

Tags: swiftui

Hi I am struggling with how to set navigation titles with SwiftUI.

What I should do is probably to set the navigation title to the LIST in BrowseWordsView() and I also do not want to set it to ContentView(). I tried adding the navigationTitle modifier directly to the BrowseWordsView() but it did not work.

How can I achieve the navigation title like the pic below? The title "Browse" will become very small and move to the top centre of the screen once the screen is scrolled down.

NavigationTitleSmall:

[image]

NavigationTitleBig:

[image]

```
enum Tabs: String{
    case study
    case browse
    case search
}

NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                // 1st view
                ContentView()
                // set the symbol and the name
                    .tabItem { Label("Study", systemImage: "pencil.line") }
                    .tag(Tabs.study)
                
                // 2nd view
                BrowseWordsView(viewModel: SearchedWordsObject(service: ExploreService()))
                // set the symbol and the name
                    .tag(Tabs.browse)
                    .tabItem { Label("Browse", systemImage: "book.pages") }

                // 3rd view
                SearchView()
                // set the symbol and the name
                    .tag(Tabs.search)
                    .tabItem { Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass") }
            }
            .navigationTitle(selectedTab.rawValue)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()

#BrowseWordsView
ScrollView {
      List(uniqueWords.sorted()) { unique in
            HStack {}
```

Comment: You should add the SwiftUI tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabView` should always be on top of the view hierarchy. If you want to setup `NavigationStack` for each tabItem. Try to wrap it outside each tabItem's content, not the TabView itself. And navigation title will automatically become inline if your contentView is a kind of List/Scrollable.

```swift
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    ContentView(navigationTitle: Tabs.study.rawValue)
        ...
}
```

The ContentView should be:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var navigationTitle: String    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ...
            .navigationTitle(navigationTitle)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        }
    }
}
```